# I'm trying to average a count from a pivot table but I'd like to do it from the source data instead

Tags: excel

I'd like to get an average jobs per day direct from the data set which drives a pivot of jobs per day at a list of sites.

I've got a large data set which lists all of the maintenance jobs performed across a nationwide estate of sites. I have already created a pivot table which shows the number of jobs completed at each site on each day which is great. It has the dates across the top and the sites down the side and where they intersect, I have the job count.

I need to produce an average number of jobs per day so i have added a column outside of the pivot which does 'total number of jobs / count of days per site' - this again works great BUT (and there's always a but  :o) when the pivot table changes size through filtering, I have to manually adjust this additional column.

Seeing as I have the source data already; there MUST be a way for me to get the averages from the source but I can't seem to figure out the right combination of `SUM` & `COUNT` formulas.

I need to filter the pivot table to create 6-8 different cuts of the site list (site size, site category, etc.) and produce an average for each groups of sites. This is why I'd like to access the source data directly so that I can pre-set each group calculation and it will auto-update when I drop in new source data.

Thanks,
Alan

`My pivot table looks like this:
        |  1/5/19  |  2/5/19  |  3/5/19 |  Grand Total         Avg Column (not in the pivot table)
Site 1  |    8     |          |    7    |       15                    7.5
Site 2  |          |    10    |    8    |       18                     9
Site 3  |    5     |     6    |    8    |       19                    6.3333`

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1361142/925350) which will show you how to change the Grand Total column into an Average.

Comment: Hi @PeterT unfortunately, that won't work because the 'numbers' in my pivot above are actually counts of text items. when I change it to 'Grand Average' instead of grand total then I get averages instead of the counts in the body of the table.